# Summing terms in jagged arrays in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, sum, sparse-matrix, large-data

I want to compute a sum of terms relating to the following jagged arrays `x`,  `tokens,` and `phi` with the same shape, and with the following forms:

- `x` has length `n`, with `x[i]` taking various lengths, (here depicted with n=5 but in reality n is very large, in the millions) [image: (looks like this)]
- `tokens` has the same shape as `x` but where each entry is a number between 1 and 200000: [image: (looks like this)]
- Lastly `phi` also has the same shape as `x` and `tokens`.

**I want to compute, for each v=1,...,200000, the sum over all products `x[i][j]* phi[i][j]` for all `i,j` where `tokens[i][j]==v`.**
Specifically I want to get out a 200000-vector where the first term is the sum over all indices `i,j` where `tokens[i][v]==1`.

Now, the only ways I could think to do this are brute-force, which are

- turn `x`, `tokens` and `phi` into sparse matrices of shape `n*200000` and then take the componentwise product `np.multiply(x,phi)`. But this is way too large since n is in the millions.
- manually get each location, something like `t = np.argwhere(tokens==v)` then take the product `x[i][t]*phi[i][t]`. But this also seems very slow since I would have to search a million arrays for 200000 different values.

Is there a better way, or which of these two would you pick?

Comment: Are you deliberately un-inlining the images that I changed in the edit? It's annoying to have to switch back and forth between tabs to see what you mean, so inline images would be better for readability IMO. If you want them to be links, I'll leave them be.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yeah I did, I felt like they're not crucial to the question and clutter the space. But I will put them back. Didn't notice you edited, and just thought that it was me!